# Arnold Custom AOVs

Tags: python, maya

I am starting working in maya and python and here is the first problem I faced:

I cannot access a newly created aiCustomAOV of my shading group (Arnold). The print gives me zero as a number of AOVs of the shading group (see the last line of the code).

If I divide the code to two parts (create an AOV and query the attribute of shading group) and run them separately I get the result, but I think it is not the proper way of doing that. Right?

Usually, when one creates a custom AOV from Render settings it automatically adds the AOV to a shading group list of aiCustomAOVS.
It seems that there is an initialization issue. How to overcome it?

Here is the code:

```
'''check whether the aiAOV_Default_Color exists'''
if not cmds.objExists('aiAOV_Default_Color'):
    customAOV = cmds.createNode('aiAOV',n='aiAOV_Default_Color', skipSelect=True)
    cmds.setAttr(customAOV+'.name','Default_Color',type='string')
    cmds.connectAttr(customAOV+'.message','defaultArnoldRenderOptions.aovList',force=1)
    cmds.connectAttr('defaultArnoldDriver.message',customAOV+'.outputs[0].driver', force=1)
    cmds.connectAttr('defaultArnoldFilter.message',customAOV+'.outputs[0].filter', force=1)
    print 'AOV has been created'
else:
    print 'No need to create a new customAOV'

''' get all shading groups'''
shadingGroup = cmds.ls('aiStandard1SG')[0]
numOfCustomAOVs = cmds.getAttr(shadingGroup+'.aiCustomAOVs', size=1)
print 'Number of custom AOVs %d' % (numOfCustomAOVs)
```

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to connect everything by yourself, just use the already implemented function:

```
import mtoa.aovs as aovs

# Create AOV
aovs.AOVInterface().addAOV('cputime', aovType='float')

# List all AOVs with their names
print(aovs.AOVInterface().getAOVNodes(names=True))
```